# Running time of DFS when checking for closely connected components

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Consider a group of k people. I want to check if every person in the group is friends with all of the other persons in the group.

In order to check if all persons are friends with each other, I would run a DFS on each person, checking if they are friends with k-1 persons. If so, it can be concludeded that they are all friends with each other.

A DFS has the running time O(V+E). Is the running time still O(V+E), if I do a DFS for each person?

Comment: I just started an algorithms course not long ago, so I'm not that into running time, but I have a feeling that it should be something like O(k*(k+E)),  because I do a DFS k times

Comment: You say "run a DFS on each person, checking if they are friends with k-1 persons", but that is not something you could/would do with DFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A DFS has the running time O(V+E). Is the running time still O(V+E),
>   if I do a DFS for each person?

No, since you are preforming the search V times you would have `O(V * (V+E))`

Likely though this is not want you want, you could do this in `O(V)` using the properties of a complete graph ie) a graph is complete if each node has degree `V-1`. Note the graph must also be simple but it should be in your case

Comment: What do you mean by using the properties of a complete graph? And could you elaborate on how I would check if a node has degree k-1? Sorry, I am very new at algorithms

Comment: @Selanim this is more about graph theory than it is algorithms. Look up "properties of complete graphs". In this case if everyone is friends with everyone your graph would be complete which makes the problem easier.

Comment: Ok, I will look it up. Thank you very much for your help